# Understanding why even though derivative exists but the derivative is not integrable in the given x range

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Why is the derivative which exists everywhere for $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ is not integrable over a region $[a,b ] \in \mathbb{R}$ having $0$ included in between a and b ?

> I can just find the derivative to be $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ - $2 \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for x= 0 now what makes it not integrable as such i can just reverse rewrite as $\int_{a}^{b} d(x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^2} ) $ isnt ? Or the term integrable means something different wrt to this function? Are there any more such type of  functions leaving the oscillating sin cos one ?

Comment: Hint: Riemann integrability of a function requires that function to be bounded.

Comment: To complement Koro's comment: Lebesgue integrability requires that the absolute value of the function be integrable, which is not the case here.

Comment: It is improperly Riemann integrable, though.

Comment: I think i get it , for integration we need the function to be continuous in the given range of x , here its havibg discontinuous derivative at x= 0 hence the result ? @koro ?

Comment: We need to make sure one conditions be satsified that integral is being performed on a continuous function . Boundness automatically gets convered ? @Arnaud

Comment: @Paracetamol: No. Being not-continuous at exactly one point in $[a,b]$ won't make the function non-integrable on [a,b], a<b.

Comment: @Paracetamol it depends on which integration theory you consider. The most general I know is Lebesgue integration, which allows for discontinuous maps. And Riemann's integration can integrate less functions than Lebesgue, but it also allows for some discontinuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are right when you suspect that integration is not the exact reverse of derivation.

The absolute value of $f'$ in your example has an integral that diverges. This means that f oscillates a lot, and that the sum of the amplitudes of each oscillation is unbounded. So the integral is only semi-convergent at 0 (improper integral). Semi-convergent integrals that are not absolutely convergent are like semi-convergent series that are not absolutely convergent: permute the terms of such a series and you can get *any limit*.

A related question is: why do we restrict ourselves to absolutely integrable functions inside the interval but meanwhile do not require this at the two ends of the interval (improper integrals)? For the kind of function you mention we could, but I suppose we would eventually run into problems while extending the theory, and this is why Lebesgue integration does not cover them.

To realize how bad things could get, consider a dense sequence $x_n$ and a sequence $\epsilon_n$ tending to $0$. Consider then the sum $$g(x) = \sum_n \epsilon_n f(x-x_n)$$
which converges and is derivable everywhere, provided you choose $\epsilon_n$ converging fast enough to $0$. Then this function has the same problem a $f$, but now this problem occurs near each point $x_n$, i.e. on a dense subset. How would you define an integration theory that covers the case of the derivative of $g$?